# Submitting AJAX form when a field is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a GET form that when submitted uses an **AJAX** request to update a php page.

I want this form to automatically submit any time a field is changed, the form contains mostly text inputs and a few dropdowns.

What I have tried:

`onchange="this.form.submit()"` - This works, but instead of AJAXing the data to the php page, it actually redirects me to the page, which is a no go.

`<input type="submit">` - I would like this to be a last resort, because I want the form to send automatically, **but it does work otherwise**.

I know that sending a form every input change isn't usually a good idea, so ideally I would like it to send the form 1-2 seconds after inactivity (After inputting something obviously) - if that isn't possible, then every time a field is changed would be acceptable as its a low traffic server.

So my question is, what is the proper way to send a form via ajax automatically?

My current :

```
                     <form method="GET" id="submitRequest" action="showTable.php">
                        <th><input type="text" id="SSeries" name="SSeries" class="form-control"></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="SModel" name="SModel" class="form-control"></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="SSerial" name="SSerial" class="form-control"></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="SColor" name="SColor" class="form-control"></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="SStorage" name="SStorage" class="form-control"></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="SCarrier" name="SCarrier" class="form-control"></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="SType" name="SType" class="form-control"></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="SUPC" name="SUPC" class="form-control"></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="SStatus" name="SStatus" class="form-control"></th>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                    </form>
```

My current AJAX:

```
                       $(document).ready(function() {
                           $('#submitRequest').submit( function( event ) {
                               $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                                   data: $('#submitRequest').serialize(), // serialize the form
                                   type: $('#submitRequest').attr('method'), // GET or POST from the form
                                   url: $('#submitRequest').attr('action'), // the file to call from the form
                                   success: function(response) { // on success..
                                        showTable();
                                   }
                               });
                               event.preventDefault();
                            });
                        });
```

Comment: Please add some code, so that we can check the issue

Comment: @Ms.Nehal I added my code, however I don't think its so much a problem with my code as it is not knowing how to send the form properly.

Comment: your input tags doesn't have `type` attribute

Comment: @Ms.Nehal Huh, interesting how I didn't notice that. Didn't solve the question though

Answer (score 4):

try this:

When input value change then form will submit,

```
jQuery("#submitRequest input").change(function(){
    $('#submitRequest').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix my problem by simply changing my jquery selection and function.

I changed it from

`$('#submitRequest').submit( function( event ) {`

To

`$('.submitForm').on('keyup', function(){`

and I added `submitForm` to each inputs class.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a post in ajax after change, and get a response from server

```
$("#submitRequest input").change(function(){
    var data = {
        SSeries : $("#SSeries").val(),
        ...
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'your_url_method',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success : function(res){
            showTable();
            console.log("Success, you submit your form" + res);
        },
        error : function(error){
            console.log(error, "Error in submit")
        }
    });

});
```